# save image in camera roll and get asset url

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

for an app I'm developing, I use UIImagePickerController to shoot a picture and store it in camera roll:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
//... some stuff ...

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], nil, nil, nil);

}
```

the image is saved, now I need to get its reference url so I try to enumerate camera roll and get the last image, but I always get the image before the one I just shot.

Anybody has an idea how to get the reference of the just saved picture?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution should fix the problem:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:((UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]).CGImage
                                 metadata:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]
                          completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"assetURL %@", assetURL);
                          }];
```

et voila:

```
assetURL assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1611E84C-24E2-4177-B49A-1C57B4A9C665&ext=JPG
```

Comment: Can you suggest me something more on how you save the image in camera roll? I can save the image but the assets URL returns "null"

Comment: You have to change completion block. I the example above the completion block simply logs the assetURL, it should be something like:                                   ALAssetsLibrary *al = [addPhoto defaultAssetsLibrary];
                                  [al assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
 where defaultAssetsLibrary is: 
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library;
}